# Deleting Swap File on VPS Server Using Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, server, swap, vps

I followed the following guide to create a 1GB swap file on my 1GB RAM Ubuntu 18.04 VPS: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-18-04

However after getting to the following step:

```
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

I am shown the following error:

```
root@ABC123:~# sudo swapon /swapfile
swapon: /swapfile: swapon failed: Operation not permitted
```

Which would suggest that my VPS host does not allow swap files to be created, and that I'm not a "true" root user.

How do I now reclaim that 1GB swap file space I had allocated? My VPS storage is now showing 1GB less storage after creating it.

I've rebooted the server and the 1GB is still taken up by the swap file.

```
root@ABC123:~# sudo swapoff -v /swapfile
```

Results in:

```
swapoff /swapfile
swapoff: Not superuser.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The swap file is a normal file. Simply remove it with

```
sudo rm -f /swapfile
```

and the disk usage should show that the occupied 1GiB is now free.

Comment: I can't believe it was something so simple, not sure how I missed this but as a newbie anything is possible. Thank you!